# UK Standard Visitor visa refusal for Assessment and Interview in the UK Army- refused V4.2(a) (c)

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

I have received a refusal for a UK visit visa. Below is the relevant text of the refusal. What does this mean and what steps can I take to significantly increase my chances of success in a potential new attempt to apply?

> The Decision
>
> I have refused your application for a visit visa because I am not
>   satisfied that you met the requirements of paragraph(s) V4.2.of the
>   Appendix V: Immigration Rules for Visitors because:
>
> - In order to be able to make a decision on whether or not to grant you entry clearance in this category i have taken into account your
>     stated circumstances in Nigeria, the reason for your visit and your
>     proposed travel arrangements.
> - You state that you wish to travel to the UK for 4weeks to attend the interview and assessment stage in you application to join the British
>     Army. You have provided a letter from the British Army which states
>     that this event will be held 12th - 14th December, a period of 3 days.
>     Given this, your plans for the remainder of your time in the UK lack
>     clarity.
> - I note that you have stated that your cousin in the UK will provide the funds for your trip but in order to make a decision on your
>     application it is reasonable to assess your personal circumstances in
>     Ghana as part of my overall assessment of your application.
> - You have declared on your application form that you are employed by ABC Company and that you derive a net monthly income of 1,000ghs
>     (£198.76 OANDA rate of exchange on 17/11/2016) from this employment.
>     You have provided a bank statement in your name from Fidelity Bank
>     which shows a closing balance of 1,742.97ghs (£346.43) on 08 November 2016.   > Whilst this statement show payment with the reference of 'SafeDrive' these are deposited into the account in cash therefore the
>     fact that these transactions appear on your statement hold little
>     corroborative value in determining that your employment is as stated by
>     you.
> - You have provided a further account in your name from Barclays which shows a closing balance of 2,236.35ghs (£444.50) on 11 November 2016.
>     Again the funds  in this account are an accumulation of cash deposits
>     that are inconsistent with your stated income.
> - Given the statement you have made and the documentary evidence you have presented to support your application I am not satisfied that
>     your circumstances in Ghana, coupled with your reasons for wishing to
>     travel to the UK at the end of your proposed visit.
> - In light of all the above, I am not satisfied that you have demonstrated that you are a genuine visitor and will leave the United
>     Kingdom at the end of your visit. Your application has therefore been
>     refused under paragraph V4.2(a) and (c) of the immigration rules.
>
> Further Applications
>
> Any future UK visa application you make will be considered on their
>   individual merits; however you are likely to be refused unless the
>   circumstances of you application change.
>
> In relation to this decision there is no right of appeal or right to
>   administrative review.

Please any advice on what to do because my application was assessed based on my circumstances in Nigeria but I am a Ghanaian and also the Army has given me another date for assessment in 2017.

Comment: Have you asked the Army if they can provide advice?

Comment: They got you on funds parking and opacity, those are explained along with corrective measures in the linked question.  Given that Ghana has the highest refusal rate for about 20 years now, it's hard to see why you sent in an application of such reduced quality. Anyway...  Read the linked question/answer and let us know if you have something unique to ask. Thanks